# Why is Twitchtv API Stream only display “offline” for each channel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitch

This is a FreeCodeCamp project in which I am supposed to show whether or not a channel is live. However, in the list of the channels I've created, there are some channels that are live and some channels that doesn't exist. Still, no matter what, when I tried it test it out in my codepen, it's still displaying "Offline", even through some should be displaying "The Account doesn't exist" or "Online". I still couldn't figured it out. I did test the url to make sure it's working and it's working. Here's one example: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/OgamingSC2?client_id=egn4k1eja0yterrcuu411n5e329rd3".

Here's my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  getSteams();

});

var channels = ["BasicallyIDoWrk", "FreeCodeCamp", "Golgothus", "maatukka", "Vinesauce", "brunofin", "comster404", "OgamingSC2"];

  var cb = "?client_id=egn4k1eja0yterrcuu411n5e329rd3";

function getSteams() {

  for (var channel in channels) {
    var indchannel = channel;

  $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + indchannel + cb,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        //action: 'query',
        format: 'json',
      },
    success: function(data) {

      var game;
      var status;

      if(data.stream === null) {
        game = "Offline";
        status = "offline";
      } else if (data.stream === undefined) {
        game = "The Account doesn't exist";
        status = "Account is closed";
      } else {
        game = data.stream.game;
        status = "online";
      };

       $("#channels").append('<div class="indbox"><a target="_blank" href="#">'+ game +'</a></div>');
    }

  });
  }
}
```

Here's my codepen in action: https://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/EWooLK. I know that it's not completed. I will finish the rest once I make sure the api is displaying the data correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  getSteams();
  
});

var channels = ["BasicallyIDoWrk", "FreeCodeCamp", "Golgothus", "maatukka", "Vinesauce", "brunofin", "comster404", "OgamingSC2"];

  var cb = "?client_id=egn4k1eja0yterrcuu411n5e329rd3";

function getSteams() {
  
  for (var channel in channels) {
    var indchannel = channel;
  
  
  $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + indchannel + cb,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        //action: 'query',
        format: 'json',
      },
    success: function(data) {
    
      var game;
      var status;
      
      if(data.stream === null) {
        game = "Offline";
        status = "offline";
      } else if (data.stream === undefined) {
        game = "The Account doesn't exist";
        status = "Account is closed";
      } else {
        game = data.stream.game;
        status = "online";
      };
      
       $("#channels").append('<div class="indbox"><a target="_blank" href="#">'+ game +'</a></div>');
    }
  
  
  });
  }
}
```

```css
html, body{
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display:block;
}
.container {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  position: relative;
}
.logobox img {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.con-button {
  background-color: white;
 border: none;
 margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
 padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
 color: rgb(100,65,164);
  font-size: 20px;
}
.activate {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #6441A4;
}
.divider hr {
  border-top: 1px solid #6441A4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="twitchtvarea">
      <div class="logobox">
        <img src="https://s6.postimg.org/bay7stotd/Twitch_Purple_RGB.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="twitchbox">
        <div class="controls">
          <button id="c-all" class="con-button" type="button">All</button>
    <button id="c-online" class="con-button" type="button">Online</button>
    <button id="c-offline" class="con-button" type="button">Offline</button> 
        </div>
        <div class="divider"><hr></div>
        <div id="channels">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is your for loop. Javascript `for in` loops are used for iterating keys in an object. In the case of an array, the key is the index, meaning the following...

```
for (var channel in channels) {
```

Will set `channel` to:

```
0
1
2
...
```

Which will result in your URL looking like:

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/0
```

What I assume you want is the channel name from the `channels` array, so that your URL will look like:

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/SomeChannelName
```

You can fix your for loop one of two ways. The first is the more traditional for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i > channels.length; i++) {
    var indchannel = channels[i];

    // perform your ajax calls here...
}
```

Or you could use the a [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control) method, which calls a function for each item in an array.

```
channels.forEach(function(indchannel, index, arr) {
    // perform your ajax calls here...
});
```

Comment: Thanks!! It works! However, what about the channels that doesn't exists? It should be displaying "Account doesn't exist"..

Comment: That's a separate question, but the short answer is because your checks for `null` and `undefined` are interchangeable; `null` and `undefined` basically evaluate to the same "falsey" state. Try using `typeof data.stream === 'null'`.

Comment: I think I sorta figure out how to get an undefined status. If I use `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/`, I was able to get the `error: Not Found`. Example: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/derpddd?client_id=egn4k1eja0yterrcuu411n5e329rd3. Also, I did notice that if I use "streams" in place of "channels" in the url, I'm able to get the link to channel. So I'm trying to figure out the method of getting the channels status through stream url...

Comment: Yes, retrieving a proper status from the API seems like the right approach. If you have other questions as you progress, make sure you ask them as separate questions on SO. Also, don't forget to accept this answer.